# Why is blender smoothing almost everything, but not everything?

Tags: modeling, objects, topology, obj

I'm new to Blender, but I really wanted to take advantage of the sculpting. I exported a OBJ file from Maya, so I can sculpt more details on to the model. However, when I switch to sculpt mode, some areas don't smooth out. I'v tried smoothing, and decimating. I'm trying to avoid bouncing between Maya and Blender. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I retopologized the model in Maya. Do I need to edit the polygons, or is it just an issue between Maya and Blender?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Is auto smoothing option enabled? Are lines marked as sharp? Did those lines connected?

Comment: another common error is that the normals on some of the faces are inverted.